# How to combine MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
id |   id_item      | 
1  |   T0001        | 
2  |   T0002        |
2  |   T0003        |
3  |   T0004        |
```

and I want to change it like this:

```
id |    id_item           | 
1  |   T0001,T0002        | 
2  |   T0001,T0003        |
2  |   T0001,T0004        |
3  |   T0002,T0003        |
4  |   T0002,T0004        |
5  |   T0003,T0004        |
```

and I want save in table `item_2` like this:

```
    id |   id_item      | 
    1  |   T0001        | 
    2  |   T0002        |
    3  |   T0001        |
    4  |   T0003        |
    5  |   T0001        |
    6  |   T0004        |
    7  |   T0002        |
    8  |   T0003        |
    9  |   T0002        |
   10  |   T0004        |
   11  |   T0003        |
   12  |   T0004        |
```

Does anyone know how to do this by using PHP or MySQL?

Comment: honestly the first set up is considered the best https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

You can generate this output via the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(t1.id_item, ',', t2.id_item) AS id_item
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
WHERE
    t2.id > t1.id
ORDER BY
    t1.id,
    t2.id
```

If you wanted to insert this data, you can use the above select to do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` into a new table.  I mention new table, because it probably would not make much sense to store CSV and non CSV data in the same column.  Actually, I don't at all recommend storing CSV data in the first place.  Instead, just generate it if you need it in your presentation layer using a query similar to what I have given above.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @IlhamPrasetya Is there any reason why you unaccepted this answer?